# Two or More AutoCompleteTextView are not working

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am a webdeveloper and trying to implement a logic in Android Application with 3  AutoCompleteTextView. I tried with one AutoCompleteTextView and it worked normally. When I have 3 AutoCompleteTextView, it is not working. Please help me with this.

This is my layout code.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView  android:id="@+id/textExecutive"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_executive" />
<AutoCompleteTextView  android:id="@+id/textSupervisor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_supervisor" />
<AutoCompleteTextView  android:id="@+id/textManager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_manager" />
```

This is in onCreate

```
textExecutive = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textExecutive);
    textSupervisor= (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textSupervisor);
    textManager= (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textManager);

String[] executives = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.executives_array);
    String[] supervisors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.supervisors_array);
    String[] managers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.managers_array);


ArrayAdapter<String> executivesAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, executives);

    ArrayAdapter<String> supervisorsAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, supervisors);

    ArrayAdapter<String> managersAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, managers);

textExecutive.setAdapter(celebritiesAdapter);
    textSupervisor.setAdapter(eventsAdapter);
    textManager.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Comment: what kind of error did you faced?

Comment: No Error(s). The autocomplete process is not working

Comment: _Not Working_ means what ?

Comment: Type any text which is in corresponding Array

Comment: With one AutoCompleteTextView, the dropdown with suggestions is working normally. But I am not getting suggestions when there is 2 or 3 AutoCompleteTextView s

Comment: check other Array Values. if it's have any elements means kindly type it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with,

```
 textExecutive.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textExecutive.showDropDown();
                textExecutive.requestFocus();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Similarly do other two.